# Повысить количество принятых ответов на Мете

Tags: предложение, мета, принятые-ответы

Предлагаю всем желающим повысить количество вопросов Меты с зелёной галочкой. Для этого можно пройтись по списку своих вопросов и там, где установлены красные метки и имеется хотя бы один ответ, установить галочку, которую скорее всего вы просто забыли поставить в своё время.

[Персонализированный список вопросов на Мете, где вы можете поставить галочку.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-*]%20hasaccepted%3A0%20user%3Ame%20answers%3A1)

Comment: Зачем?.,.,.,.,.

Comment: @Suvitruf наличие галочки — это логическое завершение жизненного цикла вопроса.

Comment: В случае с SO я бы согласился, в случае с метрй же,- не всегда.

Comment: @Suvitruf может Вы за отключение галочек на Мете вовсе?

Comment: Да нет, собственно. Просто на мете зачастую вопросы создаются с целью услышать различные мнения по вопросу, а не с целью найти ответ.

Comment: @Suvitruf в частности поэтому, я ограничился вопросами с красными метками, которые ставят только модераторы. Такие вопросы предполагают/получают вполне четкий ответ.

Comment: А, проглядел это уточнение. Ну да, в таких вопросах это вполне реально.

Comment: Сделал. Далеко не все вопросы на Мете предусматривают принятый ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky про все речи не идёт. Но многие из результатов предложенного поиска подразумевают возможность наличия галочки.

Comment: Парочку тривиальных принял, остальные неприемлимы