# Стоит ли напоминать о принятии ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ответы, принятые-ответы

Возможно где-то уже есть ответ на мой вопрос, но все-таки я его задам. Вот например я отвечаю человеку, он сказал что все круто, что мой ответ ему помог и все такое, но галку не нажимает. У меня возник вопрос - нужно ли ему напоминать чтобы он нажал галку, и как это делать покультурнее, потому-что мне лично кажется что это должно быть решение самого ТС. Вот когда я только начинал задавать здесь вопросы, то мне некоторые отвечающие говорили типа нажми на галку если все ок. Вот я и спрашиваю как это делать, и нужно ли делать вообще. Потому-что я заметил что на форуме довольно популярная проблема, когда ТС не принимает ответ, и вопросы висят неотвеченные.

Связанные обсуждения:

- [Что вы пишете, когда предлагаете автору вопроса принять ответ?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3399/15479)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Список шаблонных комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1222/186999)

Comment: А потом из-за скромности отвечающего и безалаберности вопрошающего (прочел ответ и свалил) висят вопросы, на которые вроде как нет ответа...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Это нормально.

Лично я обычно жду какое-то время (неделю примерно), после чего под вопросом в комментариях пишу что-то вроде:

> Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Люди, банально, могут забыть.

Были случаи, когда я в комментариях напоминал про то, что хорошо бы выбрать ответ, через много месяцев после ответа, и человек отмечал ответ как принятый.

Comment: спасибо большое :) надеюсь за плагиат здесь не заминусуете, если я вашу строку позаимствую?))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko не заминусую. На благое дело не жалко :D

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: я все сидел ждал пока можно будет принять, там 5 минут нужно было подождать, а потом отвлекся от ожидания )))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko есть ещё вот [такая инициатива](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6432/176217).

Comment: Перестаньте поднимать 3-5 годовалые вопросы. Это напрягает. Уж больно напрягает, когда думаешь, сейчас как отвечу, отвечу, а смотришь дату и думаешь, а зачем он тут.

Если ответ в вопросе уже существует, лучше автоматом выбрать ответ, да и все (если прошло уже больше месяца к примеру, уже не говоря за годы).  

Некоторые пользователи забивают на вопросы и сваливают, а они туда сюда крутятся.

Answer (score 5):

Да, напоминать нужно. Как под своими ответами, так и под чужими. Принятие ответов - это настолько же важная часть формирования базы знаний, как и их написание. Люди, не ставящие отметку о решении, сознательно нарушают правила и основные механики ресурса, проявляют эгоизм и неуважение к сообществу.

Я напоминаю цитатой из справки со ссылкой на неё же:

> [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте
>   его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Если принятие ответа будут *навязывать*, то наверняка какая-то часть вопрошающих  начнет это делать *случайным* образом.

Comment: @avp это не навязывание, а просветительская деятельность, помогающая новичку лучше интегрироваться в сообщество.