# Кажется, стоит засинонимизировать [queue] и [очередь]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю засинонимизировать [queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queue) и [очередь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c). Основной сделать русскоязычную.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово:

> [queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queue) будет **удалена** из **65** вопросов
>
> [очередь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c) будет **добавлена** к **55** вопросам
>
> **A tag synonym mapping [queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queue) → 
>   [очередь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c) will be created.**
>
> (эти значения включают удалённые вопросы и исключают пересекающиеся метки)

```
updating post history, 65 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 65 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 55 rows affected
destroying 'queue': [queue] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 115
tag remapping of [очередь] and [queue] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: А где весь этот лог выводится? Ещё я не могу найти строку типа "A tag synonym mapping queue → очередь will be created." в transifex. Судя по остальным русскоязычным фразам, она тоже должна иметь возможность перевода.

Comment: @alexolut первая часть - перед окончательным подтверждением, текстовый лог - без всякого UI после подтверждения.

Comment: @Nofate вот в первой части как раз смущает отсутствие перевода в одном из предложений.

Comment: @alexolut Может примете ответ, чтобы он выглядел "решённым"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov хорошая идея. Как раз вспомнил о [вопросе по этому поводу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6432/176217).